# USER_TAB_COLUMNS doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a dynamic form of inputs to register a user, so I need to select the columns which I have inside the users table such as (username - email - password-...etc.) so I got this code from some question around here

```
$query = " SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length ";
$query.=" FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS ";
$query.=" WHERE table_name = 'user_type' ";
$result= mysqli_query($db, $query)

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
} //end while
  } //end if
```

Then if I applied this inside PHP I get this

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Which means the select statement didn't work probably.
But when I apply it to phpMyAdmin SQL it gives me this error

> Table 'final_main.user_tab_columns' doesn't exist

Which tells me that I don't have this table inside my DB

Comment: You appear to be mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: are you sure you have created the table with correct name i.e. 'USER_TAB_COLUMNS' ?

Comment: Uhh... your error message literally answers your own question. Create the table with the columns you want, then your query will work. And your mysqli_query() is returning FALSE (because it does so when the query fails) and so your error message there is also obvious.

Comment: Looks to me like you're confusing MySQL with Oracle DB

Comment: @MarkBaker am working on Mysqli localhost database

Comment: @Kryten yes but i fixed it now , but it's still the same

Comment: @abmussani i think it's a pre-created table from mysql itself 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2656.htm

Comment: @KyleHale am not so stupid to not realize am calling a table i didn't create , i think this is a pre-created table (default) i mean look at the link above

Comment: @BishoyM - It's a pre-created table in __Oracle__ database, but not in MySQL

Comment: @MarkBaker ah , so that's it , but how can i do the same in MySQL ?

Comment: @MarkBaker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431889/how-to-query-the-column-names-of-a-table 
but what about this one ? ^^

Comment: That's somebody else that made the same mistake, confusing their databases, hence none of the answers mentioning USER_TAB_COLUMNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides schema information in the **`information_schema`** database.

(`USER_TAB_COLUMNS` is a view specific to Oracle; doesn't exist in MySQL.)

To get information about columns in a specific MySQL table, you'd use something like this:

```
SELECT c.column_name
     , c.column_type
     , c.data_type
     , c.character_maximum_length
     , c.numeric_precision
     , c.numeric_scale
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_name    = 'user_type'    -- table name
   AND c.table_schema  = 'final_main'   -- database name
 ORDER BY c.ordinal_position;
```